# Swift 3 - Download JPEG image and save to file - macOS

Tags: swift3, xcode8, macos-sierra

I have a downloader class that downloads a file based on a given URL which then calls a completion passing it the contents of the file as NSData.

For the project that I'm using this in, the URL will be a JPEG image. The downloader works perfectly; I can use the result into NSImage and show it in a Image View Controller.

I would like to be able to save that NSData object to file.

After quite some time researching the internet on Google, StackOverflow, etc. and trying many suggestions, I cannot get the file to save.

Here is a playground of the Downloader class and my attempt to save the file:

```
//: Playground - noun: a place where people can play

import Cocoa

class NetworkService
{
    lazy var configuration: URLSessionConfiguration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
    lazy var session: URLSession = URLSession(configuration: self.configuration)

    let url: NSURL

    init(url: NSURL)
    {
        self.url = url
    }

    func downloadImage(completion: @escaping ((NSData) -> Void))
    {
        let request = NSURLRequest(url: self.url as URL)
        let dataTask = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) { (data, response, error) in
            if error == nil {
                if let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse {
                    switch (httpResponse.statusCode) {
                    case 200:
                        if let data = data {
                            completion(data as NSData)
                        }
                    default:
                        print(httpResponse.statusCode)
                    }
                }
            } else {
                print("Error download data: \(error?.localizedDescription)")
            }
        }
        dataTask.resume()
    }

}

let IMAGE_URL = NSURL(string: "https://www.bing.com/az/hprichbg/rb/RossFountain_EN-AU11490955168_1920x1080.jpg")

let networkService = NetworkService(url: IMAGE_URL!)

networkService.downloadImage(completion: { (data) in

    data.write(to: URL(string: "file://~/Pictures/image.jpg")!, atomically: false)

})
```

The playground console show nothing at all. Can anyone spot why its not working?

NOTE: The target is **macOS**, not iOS. Also, I'm a swift noob...

I did try this:

```
networkService.downloadImage(completion: { (imageData) in
    let imageAsNSImage = NSImage(data: imageData as Data)
    if let bits = imageAsNSImage?.representations.first as? NSBitmapImageRep {
        let outputData = bits.representation(using: .JPEG, properties: [:])
        do {
            try outputData?.write(to: URL(string: "file://~/Pictures/myImage.jpg")!)
        } catch {
            print("ERROR!")
        }
    }

})
```

Comment: I did come across that one and tried that, but I had the same result. No image.jpg file was created.... Editing above to show the try...

Comment: I've retracted my close vote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be a permission issue. You may try:

```
let picturesDirectory = FileManager.default.urls(for: .picturesDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0]
let imageUrl = picturesDirectory.appendingPathComponent("image.jpg", isDirectory: false)
try? data.write(to: imageUrl)
```

It does work for me:
[image]

Comment: Just tried this one in the playground. Still no image.jpg file created.

Comment: @Johnno13 playground is sandboxed you need to test it in a real project

Comment: * facepalm * - 
data.write() didn't work in the actual project, but the above method did.